# ¿Cómo solucionar error de Prohibido en el módulo de paypal para prestashop 1.7.6.3?

Tags: paypal, prestashop1.7, modular

[[image: Imagen de Errores en consola]

Tengo el módulo paypal oficial versión para prestashop 1.7.6.3, al seleccionar el método de pago via paypal no hay problema, al seleccionar vía tarjeta crédito/débito salta la advertencia de prohibido, los errores de consola son los siguientes:

```
    Invalid X-Frame-Options: “ALLOWALL” header from “https://www.paypal.com/inlinepaymentwall/payment-selection” loaded into “https://vcrcomercial.com/pedido?controller=order”.

   Content Security Policy: Ignoring “'unsafe-inline'” within script-src or style-src: nonce-source or hash-source specified

   Content Security Policy: Directive ‘child-src’ has been deprecated. Please use directive ‘worker-src’ to control workers, or directive ‘frame-src’ to control frames respectively.

    Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.paypalobjects.com/web/res/fdc/fa2ee66f52a828acd62fd46a65c83 (“base-uri”).

    Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).
```

Comment: Échale un ojo a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298608/content-security-policy-the-pages-settings-blocked-the-loading-of-a-resource) y asegúrate que tienes el módulo de PayPal actualizado a su última versión.

Comment: El modulo esta actualizado, ya había revisado esa pregunta con anterioridad, pero no eh podido dar con la solución de momento, incluso desactive temporalmente la seguridad CSP para ver avances, pero el resultado fue el mismo